# dming a user doesn't work anymore, discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So i made a simple command for dming users that are in the same server as the bot time ago, and it always worked fine, but it is giving this error now for some reason:

```
throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, request);
            ^

DiscordAPIError: Unknown User
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\Tommaso\Documents\GitHub\bbq-bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:298:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\Tommaso\Documents\GitHub\bbq-bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:50:14)
    at async UserManager.fetch (C:\Users\Tommaso\Documents\GitHub\bbq-bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\UserManager.js:69:18) {
  method: 'get',
  path: '/users/55427571831406634',
  code: 10013,
  httpStatus: 404,
  requestData: { json: undefined, files: [] }
}
```

Code here:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'dm',
    description: 'dms a user',
    async execute(message, args, client, config) {

        // Variables and Conditions
        const dmToSend = args.slice(1).join(" ");
        const attachmentToSend = message.attachments.map(att => att.url);

        if (message.author.id !== config.ownerid)
            return message.channel.send("This command is for the bot owner only")

        if (!args[0]) return message.channel.send("Please put a user id")

        if (message.attachments.size == 0) {

            client.users.fetch(args[0]).then((user) => {
                user.send({ content: dmToSend })
            })

        } if (message.attachments.size !== 0) {

            client.users.fetch(args[0]).then((user) => {
                user.send({ content: dmToSend + attachmentToSend })
            })

        }

    }
}
```

It always worked fine as i said, and i don't understand what is happening, i think is because of the changes in the client const in djs v13, in case that's the problem here's my intents:
`const client = new Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES", "DIRECT_MESSAGES"], partials: ["CHANNEL"] });`

Comment: Hello Tommaso, error code 10013 (on poor windows OSs) is usually a SOCKET ERROR. It might be not related at all to Discord.js

Comment: Really weird, i never encountered an error originating from Windows for what i remember

Comment: `DiscordAPIError: Unknown User` means that the user id is invalid (or the user does not exist)... Discord IDs are mostly 18 characters long, but yours is 17. Are you sure that it is an existing user id?

Comment: Add `MESSAGE` partial as well, or remove it all together, you're missing the `GUILD_MEMBERS` intent as well

Comment: @Variable i added the `MESSAGE` partial and `GUILD_MEMBERS`, client now looks like this: `const client = new Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES", "GUILD_MEMBERS", "DIRECT_MESSAGES"], partials: ["CHANNEL", "MESSAGE"] });` But it still gives the error, i also enabled gateaway intents in my discord application, still nothing

Comment: Software like antivirus / firewall on windows (windows defender for instance) could be blocking the socket's connection. Please have a look at some of these threads: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=error+code+10013

Answer (score 0):

Bot cannot send message to user if that user is not in same guild with your bot.

Comment: 1. That would throw a different error. 2. The OP said `i made a simple command for dming users that are in the same server as the bot`.

Comment: Try to remove fetch block, just find that user in cache

Answer (score 0):

instead of `client.users.fetch()` try this

````js
const user = await message.client.users.fetch(args[0].replace(/\D/g, '')).catch(() => { });
if (!user) return message.channel.send({ content: 'No user found' }); // if the id or mention is not valid throw an error

// the regex allows you to provide both mentions and userID as parameters

user.send({ content: 'test' });```
````